# SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Tags: angular, popper.js

I have recently installed `popper.js` using the below comment

`npm install --save popper.js angular-popper`

Then, I add the below in `angular.json`

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"
]
```

But when I run the application I am getting the error as below in `scripts.js`,

> SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

So, as per [This documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-popper) I tried importing through `app.module.ts` as well. But no luck.

Comment: Try and import the UMD module? ```Popper.js/dist/umd```

Comment: @Terrance00 I have just tried and cool it is working. What is the difference between `popper.js` in the root and the one inside the `umd`? Post this as an answer though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Posting answer for future wanderers:

When importing popper.js, use the *UMD* distribution.

angular.json

```json
scripts:[
    //...
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    //...
]
```

The reason for this is because this distribution uses a standardized way of declaring JS libraries, called **Universal Module Definition**.

More info:

https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: moving forward, is this applicable for all third party modules in angular?

Comment: I am currently dealing with consuming an old library with angular - the ```scripts``` import should be used only if you absolutely have to IMO. 

I much prefer having typed interfaces to work with and doing a per usage import. Then let webpack handle the distribution.

That being said - sometimes you just have these dependencies and then a UMD version works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

is easy to solve, change `bootstrap` or `bootstrap.min` into `bootstrap.bundle` or `bootstrap.bundle.min` because these files contain popper.js. Popper is what is causing the problem.